# When sending a function as a parameter inside another function, do I take the first function key (synchronization)

Tags: java, multithreading, function, synchronization

My question is this:
suppose I have these lines:

```
Person p, q;
p.go(q.getAddress());
```

Now, the functions go() and getAdress() are synchronized.
suppose the function getAddress() will take some time to return, in that time, will the go() function be locked? meaning: will p get the "key" for the synchronization of the go() function?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A side note: as a language feature, `synchronized` can make you think that you lock sections of *code*. You should resist this temptation: instead of locking code, you *protect your data* to ensure that some *invariants* are true everywhere except some sections where you break them for a moment.

Now let's see what happens when your expression is evaluated:

```
q.getAddress entered
q.getAddress returns
p.go entered
p.go returns
```

Neither of "synchronizations" happens within the other, and there *is* a window between `q.getAddress` and `p.go` where neither of synchronizations protect anything. Is that what you wanted to know?

Comment: when I enter q.getAddress, does that also "enters" the p.go?
My question is as follows:
when I enter q.getAddress, can another Thread enter p.go?

Comment: No and Yes. You enter `p.go` after you **leave** `q.getAddress`. The protection of `p.go` doesn't extend in any way to the evaluation of its arguments.

Comment: I have another question, maybe you can answer me:
I have a synchronized function, and inside I have a synchronized block on item T.
Inside that block I do T.wait(). Do I release both keys or only the T key? Thanks!

Comment: Only the T key. (And please write "synchronized methods" not "functions", it's important they're methods).